# sticky navigation skips a few pixels when adding class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://kchang.myshopify.com/

I'm trying things out and i can't figure out why when you scroll down, the navigation menu kind of skips a few pixels and snaps. I [jsfiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/j44xdv3m/6/) it independently and cant seem to reproduce it.

```
.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

Does it have something to do with my fixed class?

Comment: I'm looking at the site and can't find the JavaScript that triggers the class change - can you reproduce it in your question please? (It's a good idea to do that as a general rule of thumb anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it doesn't consume any space, as soon as you take it out of the flow by setting it's position to fixed.

Simply give `.main-menu` an absolute position, so that it will always be taken out of the flow.

Comment: That's not what he's talking about, he's talking about the fact that it sticks to the top BEFORE it has actually hit the top of the window.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I think I was imagining things.